B2C Connector Deployment Is Failing (Linking Commerce Cloud With Data Cloud)

we were setting up the data cloud in local using the doc :
https://salesforce.quip.com/SdTXAqEsHUqW
we did setup the data streams and deployed it,

but the last run status is coming as failure with error:

"The security token included in the request is expired (Service:
DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID:
BM1EIBUQDJQSAQHV51N1QQM4VNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)\nThe security
token included in the request is expired (Service: DynamoDb, Status
Code: 400, Request ID:
BM1EIBUQDJQSAQHV51N1QQM4VNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)\n"

can anyone help us in identifying the resolution for the same!
